# How to set sign out from Windows 8 and 10 automatically

Tags: windows

I want to set my machine to automatically sign out after some time when idle.

Comment: Look for auto logoff screen saver

Comment: Please give us more information. How long? Is this a business environment? Have you checked the options for the screensavers? What research have you done and what have you tried and how has it failed?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sleep function in windows. It's configured this way:

1. Open `control panel`
2. `View by: Small icons` (upper right corner)
3. `Power options`
4. `Change plane settings` (on your selected plan)
5. `Put the computer into sleep` and choose a preffered time